# multi column index order for order by

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have created the following multi column index

```
CREATE INDEX ON message_log (website,  in_use, insert_timestamp);
```

However when I perform the following query, it does not seem to be using the query as it's taking a very long time to complete.

```
select id from message_log where website = 'forgezilla' AND in_use = false ORDER BY insert_timestamp NULLS FIRST;
```

Can the multi column index be used for order by? if so did I create the ordering wrong when creating the index?

Comment: If the data or index is new, `VACUUM ANALYZE message_log` might help. But please read [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/11397).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your given index cannot be used for the ORDER BY.  You can see this by doing `set enable_sort=off` and then explaining the query, you get a sort anyway because that is the only way PostgreSQL can get the job done.

But if you create the correct index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON message_log (website,  in_use, insert_timestamp NULLS FIRST);
```

then it will be used for the ORDER BY.